# iFrame contents not scrolling horizontally

Tags: html, css, iframe

iFrame in a JSF, the contents inside the frame aren't fully displayed, even though when i extend the width of the frame (more than 950px)the page contents start to appear but beyond 
the container width , i want it to have scrollbar instead

```
<ui:composition template="/layout/layout.xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"> 

    <ui:define name="body"> 
        <iframe src="www.mysource.com"  width="950px"></iframe>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

am using a template , which uses a css file , could the css file need some changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `overflow: scroll` needs to go on the inner document, preferrably on `<html>`, but alternatively on `<body>`. The same is true for the `width: 900px;`.

p.s. `scrolling` is no longer supported HTML5.